# JavaScript to add class to (li) Parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some JavaScript code that currently gets the URL of a website, splits the URL to a particular string and stores it in a variable

I then have an `if` statement which, depending on that string, will add a class to my links. However, I'm struggling to assign a class to the `li` parent, in this case I need it to be:

```
<li class="nav-item parent open">
```

Anyone have any ideas?

**The relevant JavaScript code is below**

```
const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll("nav ul li a")

var url = window.location.href;

url = url.split("/");

if (url[2] === "s.codepen.io") {
    navLinks[1].classList.add("active");
    alert(navLinks[4]);
    navLinks[4].classList.add("open");
} else {
    navLinks[3].classList.add("active");     
}
```

Can be seen here - https://codepen.io/Carrot654321/pen/YazXBv

Comment: So why are you selecting the anchor if you want to add it to the li? So select the parentNode

Answer (score 2):

You can use the *Element* [`closest(selector)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method.
(To not confuse with [jQuery synonym](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method)

```
(a-native-element).closest('li').classList.add('...')
```

Comment: Or simply adjust the selector to only fetch the `<li>` elements and not the links.

Comment: @Andreas I think the OP wants to add a class to the links as well: *I then have an IF statement that depending on that string will add a class to my links.*

Comment: `classList` is a property of the underlying HTMLElement and not a property of the jQuery object. `jQuery('someSelector').closest('li').classList…` will fail, use `….closest('li')[0].classList…`

Comment: @Stphane No, check the documentation [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

Comment: @Ele I thought you were using jQuery.

Comment: @Stphane no problem! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery addClass() function.

```
navLinks[1].addClass("active");
```

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/addclass/